# Multiple checkboxes to insert text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am making a userform to input various information into a letter.  Part of the userform are five checkboxes.  Based on different combinations of the checkboxes I want to insert a different line of text.  I can do it with many If statements but I would like to think there is a better, more efficient way of checking which boxes are checked and which ones aren't.  Maybe with an array?  I'm still learning and am not totally sure how to go about completing an array/using the information later.  Any help is appreciated and I can provide any other information that may be needed.

I'm hoping for something like

```
ifb = true
sop = false
plans = false
```

Will insert "Invitation for Bids Booklet."

```
ifb = false
sop = true
plans = true
```

Will insert "Schedule of Prices and Contract Plans."

```
ifb = true
sop = true
plans = true
```

Will insert "Invitation for Bids Booklet, Schedule of Prices and Contract Plans."

This is the If statement that I have right now and would have to keep going until I have covered every scenario.

```
If inputIFBSectHeader.Value = True & inputSOPSectHeader.Value = False & _
        inputPlansSectHeader.Value = False & inputPenSectHeader.Value = False & _
        inputCQSectHeader.Value = False Then
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("modifications").Range.InsertBefore "Invitation for Bids booklet."
    End With
End If
```

I know I have something wrong with the insert part but that's also what got me thinking that there had to be an easier/more efficient way.

Comment: At the very least, you need to provide an example of what kinds of results you expect. And posting the (perhaps inefficient) `If` statements would also help us understand what you have in mind.

Comment: I updated the question to provide some more information.  I hope it gives an idea of what I hope to get.

Comment: Mmmm, OK... One way to go about this would be to assign each checkbox a number that, when you add the numbers of the *checked* boxes you'll get a unique result for each combination. For example, assign them the values 2, 4, 8. If only the first is checked, the sum is 2; first + second: 6; first and third: 10; second, only: 4; and so on. Use a `Select Case` for each possible result. `Select Case` is faster then `If`.

Comment: Ok so with 5 checkboxes I would go with 2, 4, 8, 16, 32?  How do I set the value to the checkbox? Then I'm assuming I put that to an `Integer`.  I found how to use `Select Case`.  Also, how to call only the checked boxes?

Comment: You could use the Tag property of the controls, for example, or make it part of the control names. You need to query each control whether or not it's checked, same as you do currently.

Comment: Another possibility would be to keep a running sum when the user checks/unchecks the boxes.

Comment: You only need to do one calculation to benefit from the Select Case approach, e.g. allcbs = -(2*cint(IFBSectorHeader)+4*cint(inputSOPSectHeader)+etc.). Or you could use cstr(-cint(IFBSectorHeader)) & cstr(-cint(inputSOPSectHeader))&etc. to give you a 5 character string of "00000", "00001" etc., which might add clarity to your Select Case. As long as you can only have results True and False, that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @CindyMeister I accomplished what I needed.  Here is what I came up with.

```
' IFB
If Me.inputIFBSectHeader.Value = True Then
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ifbSectHeader").Range
    ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("headerIFBBB").Insert _
            Where:=oRng
    modCalc = modCalc + 2
End If

' SOP
If Me.inputSOPSectHeader.Value = True Then
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("sopSectHeader").Range
    ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("headerSOPBB").Insert _
            Where:=oRng
    modCalc = modCalc + 4
End If

' Plans
If Me.inputPlansSectHeader.Value = True Then
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("plansSectHeader").Range
    ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("headerPlansBB").Insert _
            Where:=oRng
    modCalc = modCalc + 8
End If

' XSects
If Me.inputPlansSectHeader.Value = True Then
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("xSectsSectHeader").Range
    ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("headerXSectsBB").Insert _
            Where:=oRng
    modCalc = modCalc + 16
End If

' PenInk
If Me.inputPenSectHeader.Value = True Then
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("penInkSectHeader").Range
    ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("headerPenInkBB").Insert _
            Where:=oRng
    modCalc = modCalc + 32
End If

' CQ
If Me.inputCQSectHeader.Value = True Then
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("cQSectHeader").Range
    ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("headerCQBB").Insert _
            Where:=oRng
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("cQDate").Range.InsertBefore inputCQDateM & " " & _
            inputCQDateD & ", " & inputCQDateY
    modCalc = modCalc + 64
End If

Select Case modCalc
    Case 2   ' IFB
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("modifications").Range.InsertBefore vbNewLine & secondPara & _
                    "Invitation for Bids booklet." & vbNewLine
    Case 4   ' SOP
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("modifications").Range.InsertBefore vbNewLine & secondPara & _
                    "Schedule of Prices." & vbNewLine
    Case 6   ' IFB,SOP
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("modifications").Range.InsertBefore vbNewLine & secondPara & _
                    "Invitation for Bids booklet and Schedule of Prices." & vbNewLine
    Case 8   ' Plans
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("modifications").Range.InsertBefore vbNewLine & secondPara & _
                    "Contract Plans." & vbNewLine
    Case 10  ' IFB,Plans
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("modifications").Range.InsertBefore vbNewLine & secondPara & _
                    "Invitation for Bids booklet and Contract Plans." & vbNewLine
    Case 12  ' SOP,Plans
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("modifications").Range.InsertBefore vbNewLine & secondPara & _
                    "Scedule of Prices and Contract Plans." & vbNewLine
    Case 14  ' IFB,SOP,Plans
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("modifications").Range.InsertBefore vbNewLine & secondPara & _
                    "Invitation for Bids booklet, Schedule of Prices, and Contract Plans." & vbNewLine
    Case 16  ' XSects
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("modifications").Range.InsertBefore vbNewLine & secondPara & _
                    "Cross-Sections." & vbNewLine
    Case 18  ' IFB,XSects
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("modifications").Range.InsertBefore vbNewLine & secondPara & _
                    "Invitation for Bids booklet and Cross-Sections." & vbNewLine
```